# "why not" or "why not to"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> 1. In either of the above ways morality is defined, **why not take it as a social construction?**
> 2. In either of the above ways morality is defined, **why not to take it
>      as a social construction?**

I want to say that "there are reasons not to take it as a social construction". Which of the above sentences means what I want?

Comment: Why do you want to add "to"?

Answer (score 2):

Because "why" does not take an infinitive with "to".

Normally, "Why" is a non-subject question word, that is followed by a sentence with inverted verb and subject:

> Why did you take it?

But there is a rhetorical use where "Why" effectively stands for "Why should you" or "Why would you", or "why should/would one".

So "Why take it?" means about the same as "Why should one take it?"; and "Why not take it?" means about the same as "Why would you not take it?"

Whether this use is *actually* (historically) derived from "would/should one" or not, it behaves as if it is, and does not take "to".

Comment: But what would you say about this answer: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjHqt-265HYAhWPa1AKHR5pCnMQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fenglish.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F168839%2Fwhy-not-use-to-use-difference&usg=AOvVaw3R4XU0Hbb6-TAO1ReXrXvk

Comment: Exactly, no doubt about it.

Comment: Why Not to Use Magic Quotes= that is, or can be, a title, it is not using take something as something. As a title, it would be acceptable.

Comment: @Lambie I don't get what you mean. Are you saying the answer on ELU is wrong?

Comment: "Why not to use magic quotes" is a perfectly good noun phrase (actually an embedded question), that might stand as a title, as Lambie says. But it's not something that could normally stand alone as an  utterance. By the same token "Why not to take it as a social construction?" could stand as a NP, for example "I don't know why not to take it as a social construction"; but in your second sentence above, there is no main clause. It is like saying "In either of the above ways morality is defined, a question?".